# Condemned problem : Fliping a coin until he gets a sequence of heads.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I have the following problem: There is a condemned that has the chance to be acquitted by tossing a coin. He is allowed to have how many tries he desired and the number of tosses in each try must be equal to the try number. He will be acquitted if in the first try he gets heads, or in the second try if he gets heads and heads (two toss), or in the third try if he gets heads, heads, heads (three toss) or in the *k*-th try if he gets k heads in a row. The question is: What is the total probability to the condemned be saved?

Naively, I proposed the solution bellow which are obviously wrong because, for instance, if the coin is unfair with probability of heads bigger than one half the probability bellow will be bigger than one. 
$$P = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^k = 1$$

How should I model this problem?

**EDITED:**

Let p be the probability of heads. We will have for the first three tries:

$$P = p + (1-p) \dot\ p^2 + (1-p)\dot\ (1-p)\dot\ p^3 + (1-p)\dot\ p \dot\ (1-p)\dot\ p^3 + \dots$$

Tree of the events occurrence drawn until the third try.
[image]

Comment: When computing the probability of winning on the $k$th try, you should take into account failing on all the previous tries. That is, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(\text{win on $k$th try, lose previous tries}).$$
(In your computation, you are over-counting.)

Alternatively, the expression for the probability of the complement (losing each try) is
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{7}{8} \cdots
= \prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k-1}{2^k}.$$

Comment: Under what conditions is the condemned person ever executed? Your description allows him or her to keep on with the coin flipping for ever. (Not a very interesting life, but not a death sentence $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, but "not executed" is not the same as "saved".

Comment: Have you seen the other answer? It seems more appropriated. What do you think?

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I'm sorry, but I genuinely did not understand the question. If it is rephrased using "escape" rather than "be saved", then it makes perfect sense.

Comment: The upload a picture with the purpose of help the understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P_k$ be the probability that the condemned escapes on their $k^{th}$ try.  $P_k =(1-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}P_{i})\cdot(\frac{1}{2})^k\not = P_{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$, i.e. the probability he DIDN'T escape on a previous try times the probability he flips the $k$ heads.

Using a calculator to find the first few values leads to https://oeis.org/A005329 and the result can be verified using induction:

$$P_k = \frac{1}{2^\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}\prod_{i=2}^{k}{2^{i-1}-1}$$

$$P(\text{escape})=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{P_k}\approx0.7112119$$

Comment: Do you have any reference to indicate?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in[0,1]$ be the probability of heads in a single throw, and denote by $f_n(x)$ the probability that the prisoner is not yet free after $n$ trials. Then
$$f_0(x)=1,\qquad f_n(x)=(1-x^n)f_{n-1}(x)\quad(n\geq1)\ .$$
Since $f_n$ differs from $f_{n-1}$ only in the terms having an exponent $\geq n$ it follows that the $f_n$ converge in the sense of formal  power series to an $f$ which can be written as $$f(x):=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1-x^n)\ .\tag{1}$$
The computation gives
$$\eqalign{f(x)&=x+x^2-x^5-x^7+x^{12}+x^{15}-x^{22}-x^{26}\cr &\qquad\qquad+x^{35}+x^{40}-x^{51}-x^{57}+x^{70}+x^{77}-x^{92}-x^{100}+\ldots\quad.\cr}$$
As expected in view of $(1)$ the exponents appearing here are related to the pentagonal numbers, resp., to partitions. If you take the reciprocal of $f$ you shall see the partition numbers as coefficients. In particular we see that the convergence is not only formal, but $f$ is analytic in the unit disk. Using the approximation $(2)$ one obtains $f(0.5)\approx 0.288788$, which corresponds to a probability $0.711212$ of becoming free in the limit.